# Java EE: Bind some interceptor annotations to a single one

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations, interceptor

First of all: I want to use Java EE not Spring!
I have some self defined annotations which are acting as interceptor bindings. I use the annotations on my methods like this:

```java
@Logged
@Secured
@RequestParsed
@ResultHandled
public void doSomething() {
   // ...
}
```

For some methods I want to use a single of these annotations but most methods I want to use like this:

```java
@FunctionMethod
public void doSomething() {
   // ...
}
```

Can I bundle these set of annotations to a single one? I cannot write the code in a single interceptor because for some methods I want to use them seperately too.

I know that there is a @Stereotype definition possible, but as far as I know, this is used to define a whole class not a single method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of some well-known search engine I found the solution in the documentation of JBoss Weld (Chapter 9.6 Interceptor binding with inheritance)

I can use an interceptor binding interface which is inherited from other interceptor bindings. It will look like this:

```js
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Logged
@Secured
@RequestParsed
@ResultHandled
public @interface FunctionMethod {
  // clean and empty
}
```

Now I can use the new interceptor binding on the bean method and all of the interceptors will be called:

```js
@FunctionMethod
public void doSomething() {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that you are on the right pass with a stereotype.

It's right, that the examples one finds and also the official Java EE 6 Tutorial only uses it on a class as an example (e.g. @Model), but you may as well declare @TYPE(MEHOD) in your custom annotation and then I assume that it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Of course I already tried out the Stereotype approach and I realized that at least for interceptors it is onlky useable for type annotations. The real reason is that the annotations I want to bind together are all `@InterceptorBindings`. For these a target type of METHOD and TYPE is required. But if I use a couple of them in a `@Stereotype` then this one has to be `@Target(TYPE)` too.